# Which Vedas say Shudras can learn Vedas and go to Gurukulam?

Tags: vedas, shudra, gurukul

Which Vedas say Shudras can learn Vedas and go to Gurukulam? Please give verse and source. Also, why do later texts forbid such if such verse is mentioned?

Comment: No scriptures allow this.

Comment: Shudras by definition are the person who aren't interested in reading. They are assigned the jobs accordingly.

Comment: @User29449 kk Why do some texts say to give Shudras enlightenment?

Comment: @Haridasa Enlightenment has nothing to do with shudra. It can happen to anyone spontaneously or it may takes lifetimes of spiritual practice too.

Comment: @User29449 gotch ya, but if a Shudra is interested in learning is he/she not allowed to?

Comment: @Haridasa How can someone be a shudra and be interested in learning at the same time? Have you seen a rabbit that meows?

Comment: @User29449 was born into a shudra family I should have stated instead.

Comment: @Haridasa So what? Shudra status is not determined by Birth. Where is that written?

Comment: @User29449 I see we're doing it based on character and conduct.